# Is it possible to access the Context.Connectionid outside of a SignalR2 Hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We need to broadcast from the Server to the Client as seen in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr#set-up-the-client-code). In the example however, they get the hub context and send to all clients? I would like however to broadcast to the user that is can be accessed via `Context.ConnectionId` but it doesn't seem like it can be accessed outside of the Hub. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can map users in to groups, and then broadcast to that group outside the hub.

You can read more about single users groups in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections).